# How to define external overloading for PriorityQueue to manage heterogeneous type elements?

Tags: python-3.x, overloading, comparator

I want to store pairs `(prio,val)` of heterogeneous types in a python PriorityQueue. Here `val` can be either a string or a custom class object.
When `prio` are equals, the PriorityQueue (actually heapq) implementation comes to compare the second member, thus comparing a string and a custom objects.

Depending on the order the elements were stored, it comes to compare either:

1. custom_object < string
2. string < custom_object

Case 1. translates to `custom_object.__lt__(string)` and this is fine, as i can overload the `def __lt__:`method in my custom class.

Case 2. : i am stuck because i do not know how to redefine `__lt__` for strings.

Below is a MWE that inserts 3 elements with equal priorities (the value 1).
Running it results in the error message:

`TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'C'`

```
import queue

class C:
    def __init__(self,value):
        __value__ = value

    def __lt__(selfself,other):
        return 0


q = queue.PriorityQueue()
tuple1=(1,"t1")
tuple2=(1,C("t2"))
tuple3=(1,"t3")

q.put(tuple1)
q.put(tuple2)
q.put(tuple3)

print( q.get())
```

Answer (score 1):

If `a` does not supply an implementation for `a < b`, then Python will look for an implementation of `b > a` next.

```
class C:
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return 0
    def __gt__(self, other):
        return 1

c = C()

print(c < 'a')  # 0
print('a' < c)  # 1
```